# Syntax error when using except in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-except

This query works:

```
mysql> SELECT s.sno FROM students s;  
+------+  
| sno  |   
+------+   
|    1 |   
|    2 |   
|    3 |   
|    4 |   
|    5 |    
|    6 |    
|    7 |   
|    8 |   
|    9 |   
|   10 |   
+------+   
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This query also works:

```
mysql> SELECT t.sno FROM take t WHERE t.cno = 'CS112';  
+------+  
| sno  |  
+------+  
|    1 |  
|    2 |  
|    3 |  
|    4 |  
+------+   
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

BUT this query:

```
SELECT s.sno FROM students s    
EXCEPT    
SELECT t.sno FROM take t WHERE t.cno = 'CS112';
```

fails with the error:

```
mysql> SELECT s.sno FROM students s  
    -> EXCEPT  
    -> SELECT t.sno FROM take t WHERE t.cno = 'CS112';  
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n   
ear 'EXCEPT   
SELECT t.sno FROM take t WHERE t.cno = 'CS112'' at line 2
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 23):

I don't believe MySQL supports EXCEPT syntax.  Try using `NOT IN` or a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.sno 
FROM students s    
WHERE s.sno NOT IN 
(
    SELECT t.sno 
    FROM take t 
    WHERE t.cno = 'CS112'
);
```

OR

```
SELECT s.sno 
FROM students s    
    LEFT JOIN take t ON s.sno = t.sno
WHERE IFNULL(t.cno, '') != 'CS112'
```

**UPDATE**

I mocked up your data as such and it correctly returns 5 through 10:

```
create temporary table temp_students (sno int)

insert into temp_students values (1)
insert into temp_students values (2)
insert into temp_students values (3)
insert into temp_students values (4)
insert into temp_students values (5)
insert into temp_students values (6)
insert into temp_students values (7)
insert into temp_students values (8)
insert into temp_students values (9)
insert into temp_students values (10)

create temporary table temp_take (sno int, cno varchar(50))

insert into temp_take values (1, 'CS112')
insert into temp_take values (2, 'CS112')
insert into temp_take values (3, 'CS112')
insert into temp_take values (4, 'CS112')

SELECT s.sno 
FROM temp_students s    
        LEFT JOIN temp_take t ON s.sno = t.sno
WHERE IFNULL(t.cno, '') != 'CS112'
```

Comment: You are right about not supporting `EXCEPT`. Your alternative though does not produce the correct result.

Comment: The query you posted does not return that.

Comment: I mocked up your data and got 5-10 returned.  See modified answer.

Answer (score 9):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7430/8)**

```
SELECT s.sno 
FROM students s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 
                  FROM take t 
                  WHERE t.sno = s.sno 
                  AND t.cno = 'CS112')
```

Comment: This is the best answer, since it works on multiple fields as well

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
SELECT s.sno FROM students s
LEFT JOIN take t ON t.sno = s.sno AND t.cno = 'CS112' 
WHERE t.sno IS NULL;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7430/7