# Insert rows if they don't exist into a table from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I know how to make an insert of a row of values into a table using insert into. 
However, I cannot find an appropriate idiom for accomplishing the task that I have.

I have two tables. One table is the primary table and the other is an additional table. I need to insert rows that do not exist in the primary from additional table ignoring any duplicates.

I am trying to use some variations of:

```
replace into primary 
select * from additional;
```

But this obviously replaces the rows which is not what I want. Should I use `on duplicate` somehow or am I in a completely wrong direction?

EDIT:

Both of the columns have a unique surrogate key column which is just an integer value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a unique key, then the following will generate an error on the duplicate keys:

```
insert into primary(col1, . . .)
    select col1, . . .
    from secondary;
```

Here are three ways to avoid this error.  The first is `insert ignore`:

```
insert ignore into primary(col1, . . .)
    select col1, . . .
    from secondary;
```

The problem with `insert ignore` is that it ignores all errors.  So, you might miss something important other than the duplicate unique key error.

The second is `on duplicate key update`.  You need to put in a "no-op" update statement:

```
insert into primary(col1, . . .)
    select col1, . . .
    from secondary
    on duplicate key update col1 = col1;
```

This is often the easiest way.

The third is to have `join` or `not exists` logic:

```
insert into primary(col1, . . .)
    select col1, . . .
    from secondary
    where not exists (select 1 from primary where primary.keycol = secondary.keycol);
```

I think this can result in race conditions if two queries are inserting rows at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, I think the second way is the best for my purposes out of all proposed. Looks good and worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You are going in the wrong direction.  You want something like this:

```
insert into primary
(field1, field2, etc)
select distinct field_a, field_b, etc
from additional
where whatever.
```

The where clause is the spot to exclude existing records.  Apparently MySQL does not support the except keyword, so you have to use other methods.  [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092353/error-when-using-except-in-a-query) will help you with that.

Also, if primary has an autogenerated primary key, let the database generate it.  Ignore the PK field from additional.