# Except not working in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get id's from a specific table except from those ids from another table and it does not work:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 
EXCEPT 
SELECT id FROM table2
```

Comment: That is correct.  MySQL does not support `except`.

Comment: Feature request for EXCEPT: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1309

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when using except in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092353/error-when-using-except-in-a-query)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 
where id not in (SELECT id FROM table2)
```

MYSQL does not support `EXCEPT`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think mysql supports EXCEPT. Instead try this way :

```
SELECT t1.id 
FROM table1 t1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    ( SELECT 0 
      FROM table2 t2 
      WHERE t2.id = t1.id )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Not IN`

```
SELECT `id` FROM `table1` 
WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `id` FROM `table2`);
```

For more information you can take a look at 
[MySQL NOT IN() function](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php).

You can also use `Left Join`.

Answer (score 0):

there is no keyword as 'except' in mysql.

See: [Error when using except in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092353/error-when-using-except-in-a-query)

for the alternate way using `not in` and `exists`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Left Join`, as following:

```
SELECT t1.id 
FROM table1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 
    ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

For more info, You can go to [MySQL MINUS (or Except)](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-minus/)