# Having trouble with except query

Tags: mysql

I got two tables (Books and Borrowed).

I want to select all from table `Books`.
But first it will check if the `BookID` exists in the table `Borrowed` and if it does exists and its `Status`= 1, it wont be included from the select * statement.

I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
select * from Books
except
select `BookdID` where `Status`=1
```

Please help me. This are my table

Books :

```
 | BookID     | Title       | Author       |
 |:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
 | 1          | The Stars   | William Evan |   
 | 2          | Science 3   | Vhong Navaro |
 | 3          | Let It Burn | Jun Ryl      |
 | 4          | Sky Below   | Jason Midfle |
 | 5          | Wish It     | Shan Uddle   |
```

Borrowed :

```
 | BookID     | BorrowerID  | Status       |
 |:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
 | 6          | 12          | 0            |   
 | 5          | 4           | 0            |
 | 2          | 3           | 1            |
 | 18         | 6           | 1            |
 | 5          | 3           | 0            |
```

My goal output:

```
| BookID     | Title       | Author       |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| 1          | The Stars   | William Evan |   
| 3          | Let It Burn | Jun Ryl      |
| 4          | Sky Below   | Jason Midfle |
| 5          | Wish It     | Shan Uddle   |
  *(BookID 2 is is not shown because in the table `Borrowed`, BookID 2's `Status` = 1)*
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when using except in a query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092353/error-when-using-except-in-a-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select b1.* 
from Books b1
left join Borrowed b2 on b1.bookid = b2.bookid
                     and b2.`Status` = 1
where b2.bookid is null
```

See [this great explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: It says `Column 'Status' in on clause is ambiguous`, What does it mean?

Comment: It means both tables have a `status` column and the DB does not know which one to take. I updated the query and added the table name to the `status` column.

Comment: @kielou I recommend you to read the page juergen provided and then to look directly into [MySQL's `JOIN` documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). Only by understanding the way things work, you may be able to solve similar problems by yourself in the future. Actually your question has been asked before and [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16092507/1326147) also consisted of a `LEFT JOIN`, since `EXCEPT` does not exist in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you sir. I found the problem and it works.
Thank you so much.

Comment: @Armfoot Im reading while waiting for his response, and i think i can now solve the other problems that i have now thanks to juergen d..